# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, noclassdeffounderror

I recently encountered a problem where the maven repo cannot be accessed. This was resolved through:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-485

Howver, after I deleted the ~/.ivy/cache, The following java error pops up:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.xsbt$boot$Pre$$classMissing$1(Pre.scala:68)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$$anonfun$getMissing$1.apply(Pre.scala:69)
    at   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.RelativeUrlResolver.filter(RelativeUrlResolver.java:263)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.getMissing$d83f809$3a8a6f87(Pre.scala:69)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.checkLoader$2accd70c(Launch.scala:131)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$provider$1(Launch.scala:189)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0$2.apply(Launch.scala:192)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0$2.apply(Launch.scala:191)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0(Launch.scala:191)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$3.call(Launch.scala:180)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:178)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScalaProvider(Launch.scala:180)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$1.apply(Launch.scala:87)
    at xsbt.boot.Cache.newEntry(Cache.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Cache.apply(Cache.scala:12)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:90)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:89)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:160)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:142)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:178)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:91)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.internal.Trees
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 69 more
```

I am rather new with scala. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Can you please rename `~/.ivy` to some other name and do `sbt about` to verify if that may have fixed the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I managed to get it to work after deleting both ~/.sbt and ~/.ivy2 in my home directory. Deleting just ~/.ivy2 caused the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 2):

I got this exception when there were a dependency mismatch between the dependency io.gatling.highcharts and gatling-maven-plugin. Simplest solution was to use the latest of them both.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. And after checking, I've got no scala version conflict issue, no library lacking issue, no sbt issue. I also tried to delete ~/.ivy/ and ~/.sbt, no miracle. What works for me is that, **I simply deleted the scala.reflect library under ~/.m2 and reload the project**. Everything works fine now. Hope it can help.

Comment: Sometimes maven dependencies get corrupted and need a redownload. A useful command for that is `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`